# GPU is running at a high temperature even after cleaning it with a compressed air can?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, temperature

So before cleaning my computer, my GPU ran at a temperature between 90 and 100 degrees Celsius. Now that I cleaned my computer with a compressed air can, my GPU is running at a temperature of 86 degrees Celsius. Oh and when I recorded these temperatures, the system was idle, nothing running in the background.

Oh and it's worth saying that ever since I cleaned my GPU, the right monitor (I have two monitors) is kind of glitching out.

Does anyone know what may be causing this? Do I need to get a new GPU?

I have a Radeon HD 6770 gpu.

Comment: How long has it been running at such high temperatures? On my old computer the graphics card would hover around 100 degrees Celsius, and it began having issues before it simply quit on me. Granted, that took 3 years.

Comment: This is a limitation of a lot of AMD and NVidia graphics cards: they run at maximum clocks when two displays are attached. With only one display attached they will run at much lower clocks when not busy. Try having only one display atached for a while and see what the temperatures are.

Comment: I've attached one display, still the same. It's been running at a high temp for over a week now. Maybe it's time I get a new GPU, still I'm not sure.

Comment: Prior to getting an actual new GPU , you at that point have nothing to lose by reconditioning the thermal interface on the old one. You are not mentioning the speed that the fan is running at? if any overvoltage/overclock is being applied? the CCC has controls to manually mess with all that, speedfan can potentially control your thermal responces. We do not know your ambient temp? which can be important.

Comment: The clock speed determines the amount of heat it puts out. Yours appears to be stuck on high clock rates. Try changing the settings in the Catalyst Control Center. Also run SysInternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check if something is running to make the GPU go full tilt all the time.

Comment: How's your case air flow?  Do you have another pci-e card uptight with your GPU so it can't get any air flow?  Do you have cases fans, are they working?  Is your PC inside a cabinet restricting airflow? Have you checked the voltages on your 5v and 12v supplies. If there not + or - 5% that is another possible issue.  Are you overclocking anything?